# how to describe stop / start AWS EC2 instances process by schedule in Terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I trying figure out how to simply start / stop EC2 instances by schedule and EventBridge

This behavior may be easily set via AWS WEB console (`EventBridge → Rules → Create Rule → AWS service → EC2 StopInstances API call`):

[image: aws console view]

But I can't figure out how to describe this rule in Terraform

Only possible way that I found is [to create Lambda](https://gist.github.com/picadoh/815c11361d1a88419ea16b14fe044e85). But it looks like a huge overhead for this simple action. Is here any way to add `EC2 StopInstances API call` Rule with Terraform?

Comment: It can be done by using two resources for rule and for target. Can you at least add the rule you are using so I can try to come up with an answer?

Comment: `Can you at least add the rule you are using` → What I have to add? Terraform code? I guess that should be `aws_cloudwatch_event_target.name` and `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.name` resources, but I don't know what is `aws_cloudwatch_event_target` for this type of target. So I don't have any code yet

Comment: Well, in the previous step in the console you defined a schedule on which to run the rule or not?

Comment: Hmm, actually I didn't proceed to next step because it can't be described with terraform. Ok, let me try to do that

Comment: oh, I can see arn of target after creation: `arn:aws:events:ap-northeast-1:ACCOUNT-ID:target/stop-instance`, looks like it can be used as `arn` for `aws_cloudwatch_event_target`. But here is `ACCOUNT-ID` in ARN, so not sure if this resource exists by default... (so it should be created by terraform? egg and chiken problem...)

Comment: Ah, ok, no, that is what is supposed to happen when you create it with terraform.

Comment: What are the rule details and schedule? I need that information to provide an answer. :)

Comment: what details I have to add? let's say that Instance ID is `i-123456789abc` and schedule is `cron(0 0 * * ? *)`

Comment: And what should be the source of the event? EC2? CloudTrail?

Comment: what do you mean by source? If I understanding correctly source is `EventBridge` and target is `EC2`. Do you mean what service `EventBridge` should call for stopping EC2? It is not matter, but it should be managed AWS service. If we using Lambda we have to maintain Lambda code manually and I don't like it

Comment: You want to do this on a schedule, so the source would be an EventBridge cron schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, looks like it is possible to control instance running time with SSM Automation:

- variables.tf

```
variable "start_cron_representation" {
  type = string
}

variable "stop_cron_representation" {
  type = string
}

variable "instance_id" {
  type = string
}

variable "instance_type" {
  description = "ec2 or rds"
  type = string
}
```

- locals.tf

```
locals {
  stop_task_name = var.instance_type == "rds" ? "AWS-StopRdsInstance" : "AWS-StopEC2Instance"
  start_task_name = var.instance_type == "rds" ? "AWS-StartRdsInstance" : "AWS-StartEC2Instance"
  permissions = var.instance_type == "rds" ? [
      "rds:StopDBInstance",
      "rds:StartDBInstance",
      "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
      "ssm:StartAutomationExecution"
    ] : [
      "ec2:StopInstances",
      "ec2:StartInstances",
      "ec2:DescribeInstances",
      "ssm:StartAutomationExecution"
    ]
}
```

- main.tf

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ssm_lifecycle_trust" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "ssm.amazonaws.com",
        "events.amazonaws.com"
      ]
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ssm_lifecycle" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = local.permissions
    resources = ["*"]
  }
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = [
      "iam:PassRole"
    ]
    resources = [aws_iam_role.ssm_lifecycle.arn]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ssm_lifecycle" {
  name               = "${var.instance_type}-power-control-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ssm_lifecycle_trust.json
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "ssm_lifecycle" {
  name   = "${var.instance_type}-power-control-policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ssm_lifecycle.json
  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role.ssm_lifecycle
  ]
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ssm_lifecycle" {
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ssm_lifecycle.arn
  role       = aws_iam_role.ssm_lifecycle.name
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "stop_instance" {
  name                = "stop-${var.instance_type}"
  description         = "Stop ${var.instance_type} instance"
  schedule_expression = var.stop_cron_representation
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "stop_instance" {
  target_id = "stop-${var.instance_type}"
  arn = "arn:aws:ssm:ap-northeast-1::automation-definition/${local.stop_task_name}"
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.stop_instance.name
  role_arn  = aws_iam_role.ssm_lifecycle.arn

  input = <<DOC
{
  "InstanceId": ["${var.instance_id}"],
  "AutomationAssumeRole": ["${aws_iam_role.ssm_lifecycle.arn}"]
}
DOC
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "start_instance" {
  name                = "start-${var.instance_type}"
  description         = "Start ${var.instance_type} instance"
  schedule_expression = var.start_cron_representation
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "start_instance" {
  target_id = "start-${var.instance_type}"
  arn = "arn:aws:ssm:ap-northeast-1::automation-definition/${local.start_task_name}"
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.start_instance.name
  role_arn  = aws_iam_role.ssm_lifecycle.arn

  input = <<DOC
{
  "InstanceId": ["${var.instance_id}"],
  "AutomationAssumeRole": ["${aws_iam_role.ssm_lifecycle.arn}"]
}
DOC
}
```

This module may be called like:

```
module "ec2_start_and_stop" {

  source                    = "./module_folder"
  start_cron_representation = "cron(0 0 * * ? *)"
  stop_cron_representation  = "cron(0 1 * * ? *)"
  instance_id               = aws_instance.instance_name.id # or aws_db_instance.db.id for RDS
  instance_type             = "ec2" # or "rds" for RDS

  depends_on = [
    aws_instance.instance_name
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why would you switch to using SSM instead of EventBridge?

Comment: `SSM instead of EventBridge?` → Because [`aws_cloudwatch_event_rule`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_rule) == EventBridge rule? EventiBridge is a thing that triggering someting. SSM is a triggered thing